# how to change the allign of microsoft word 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

[the word file I am using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JVdWfCBpCiaEtwdW43VW1UejA/view?usp=sharing)I paste a mathematics formula into the word, then before I know it, the align of the text after it become super weird. I cannot move the text to the left, it seems automatically indentted after the formular, anyone know how to fix it?

( I believe it used to has this thing called tabstop, or someother name, so you can just move the tab and the position of the cursor will just move to that place, no need to use space key, but its gone!)
ps: you can see the picture in http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-allign-in-microsoft-word
pps:its the version of word that offers for free to college student but I don't think that is the reason

Comment: don't know.. have you tried highlighting it and hitting ctrl-L or ctrl-R, is either of those what you want?    Paste a pic of the situation. Where did you paste it from. Include screenshots, ideally so people here can repeat it, but at least so people here can see

Comment: Add a picture if you can - if you do not have reps - post the pic elsewhere and provide link - ur guess is correct - it has got to do with the tabs

Comment: If you still have trouble after reviewing my answer, please post another picture with the settings I described turned on.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to troubleshoot issues like this is to use a combination of the "ruler" and "show hidden symbols".

To display the ruler (which will show tab stops and other layout characteristics):

1. Navigate to "View" tab of ribbon
2. Check the box "display ruler"

To show hidden characters:

1. Navigate to "Home" tab of ribbon
2. Check the box with a little paragraph symbol (alternatively, use alt -> h -> 8, press them one at a time not together)

The combination of those two settings should allow you to see what the issue is, and are handy in a range of other situations too. I wouldn't recommend keeping show hidden symbols on all the time, though, as it tends to get in the way if you aren't having an issue to begin with.

Comment: I find it  must has something to do with section break, I try to delete it, but then it just automatically pop up after I start typing., I uploaded  a new screeshot at the same quora link.. thanks for your time

Comment: actually, I shared the word file, if that is more convenient for you.The weird thing happened in the last page after that formula for calculating specific heat.

Comment: I think that maybe the paper is formatted as two columns? The gray bar where the "9" should be in the ruler looks suspicious.